# slim inception_v4 retrain ValueError: All shapes must be fully defined

Tags: tensorflow

I got the following error

```
ValueError: All shapes must be fully defined: [TensorShape([Dimension(299), Dimension(299), Dimension(3)]), TensorShape([Dimension(None)])]
```

when training the inception_v4 with slim.

## Full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../models/slim/train_vienna_classifier.py", line 575, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/osman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "../models/slim/train_vienna_classifier.py", line 441, in main
    capacity=5 * FLAGS.batch_size)
  File "/home/osman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 872, in batch
    name=name)
  File "/home/osman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 658, in _batch
    capacity=capacity, dtypes=types, shapes=shapes, shared_name=shared_name)
  File "/home/osman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 685, in __init__
    shapes = _as_shape_list(shapes, dtypes)
  File "/home/osman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 77, in _as_shape_list
    raise ValueError("All shapes must be fully defined: %s" % shapes)
ValueError: All shapes must be fully defined: [TensorShape([Dimension(299), Dimension(299), Dimension(3)]), TensorShape([Dimension(None)])]
```

## The code

```
with tf.device(deploy_config.inputs_device()):
  provider = slim.dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider(
      dataset,
      num_readers=FLAGS.num_readers,
      common_queue_capacity=20 * FLAGS.batch_size,
      common_queue_min=10 * FLAGS.batch_size)
  [image, label] = provider.get(['image', 'label'])
  label -= FLAGS.labels_offset

  train_image_size = FLAGS.train_image_size or network_fn.default_image_size

  image = image_preprocessing_fn(image, train_image_size, train_image_size)
  images, labels = tf.train.batch(
      [image, label],
      batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
      num_threads=FLAGS.num_preprocessing_threads,
      capacity=5 * FLAGS.batch_size)
  labels = slim.one_hot_encoding(
      labels, dataset.num_classes - FLAGS.labels_offset)
  batch_queue = slim.prefetch_queue.prefetch_queue(
      [images, labels], capacity=2 * deploy_config.num_clones)
```

Although the sizes of images in the dataset are different, I am using the given preprocessing function for resizing them, therefore it should not return the error. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with the images but the `labels` as its shape is not defined:  `[TensorShape([Dimension(299), Dimension(299), Dimension(3)]), TensorShape([Dimension(None)])]`. The second tensor dimension is shown as `None`. So setting the labels to the correct shape should fix this issue.

Use the `tf.reshape()` function to set the shape of the labels.

Comment: how can I do that? I have modified the slim inception retrain to support multiple labels.

Comment: I got a different error now. The unknown dimension is a one-hot vector with size 1533. After I reshaping it, I got the following error ```ValueError: Shapes (32, 1533) and (32, 1533, 1533) are incompatible```

Comment: Ur batch_size is 32 and the number of classes is 1533?, then the first one is right. fix the other one.

Comment: yes, they are. I am modifying the slim inception train to support multi-label classification. Actually, the label was tf.FixedLenFeature, however to support multi-label I changed it to the tf.VarLenFeautre.

Comment: can u show me the part of the code that is giving issues?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148363/discussion-between-neouyghur-and-vijay-m).